# Detecting frames for which a face appears in a video

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, matlab-cvst

I need to detect the number of frames for which a face is appearing in a video. I looked into the sample code using CAMShift algorithm provided in the MathWorks site(http://www.mathworks.in/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-camshift.html). Is there a way of knowing whether a face has appeared in a particular frame?

I'm new to MatLab. I'm assuming the step function will return a false value if no face is detected (condition fails - similar to C). Is there a possible solution? I think using MinSize is also a possible solution.

I am not concerned about the computational burden - although a faster approach for the same would be appreciated. My current code is given below:

```
clc;
clear all;

videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('Teapot.mp4', 'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8', 'ImageColorSpace', 'Intensity');
video = VideoReader('Teapot.mp4');
numOfFrames = video.NumberOfFrames;
faceDetector    = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();
opFolder = fullfile(cd, 'Face Detected Frames');

frameCount     = 0;
shotCount      = 0;

while ~isDone(videoFileReader)

    videoFrame      = step(videoFileReader);
    bbox            = step(faceDetector, videoFrame);
    framCount = frameCount + 1;

    for i = 1:size(bbox,1)
        shotCount = shotCount + 1;
        rectangle('Position',bbox(i,:),'LineWidth', 2, 'EdgeColor', [1 1 0]);
        videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame,'rectangle',bbox,'Face');
        progIndication = sprintf('Face has been detected in frame %d of %d frames', shotCount, numOfFrames);
        figure, imshow(videoOut), title(progIndication);
    end
end
release(videoFileReader);
```

Comment: In cases like this I would expect `bbox` to return empty if nothing was found.  (Try it on an image you know has no faces in it!).

Comment: I don't think that's how it works. The Cascade Object will definitely try and detect a face in the video. It may return the smallest possible size of bbox though. I tried with a video without any faces. That's what it seems to be doing...

Comment: Really? Because I just tried it with a randomly chosen image in my workspace and it returns empty.  (You can use `isempty` to check this in your program).

Comment: Okay. I'll try it with my program and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually I tried the same program with a video without any faces in it and it was still displaying the rectangle. I didn't realise that that could actually be the minimum rectangle size.

Comment: @nkjt: Unfortunately the algorithm tends to find a set of points as a face even if there isn't a face. Therefore, it doesn't display a face in some cases while it does in other cases although a face doesn't exist. Is there a possible way to use MinSize to filter out the other cases or probably subtract sum of bbox of 2 successive frames and maintain a threshold so that sudden value changes mean the face has disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` object to detect faces in any particular frame. If it does not detect any faces, its `step` method will return an empty array.  The problem is that the face detection algorithm is not perfect. Sometimes it detects false positives, i. e. detects faces where there are none.  You can try to mitigate that my setting the `MinSize` and `MaxSize` properties, assuming you know what size faces you expect to find.